# Redirect URLs using Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, google-cloud-dns

I have a domain (example.com) already configured in Cloud DNS. With this domain I can access microservices that are in a GKE cluster. I use istio-ingressgateway IP in CloudDNS to make the association between the cluster

Now I have another domain (newexample.com) with a custom certificate for https connections. Is there a way to redirect all the requests to newexample.com to example.com? I do not want to change anything in gke/istio configuration if possible.

Comment: You can add `A` record to the `DNS` servers to point your domain to the `ingress-gateway` loadbalancer service of Istio however the question is how do you want to add your ssl certificates without modifying your `ingress-gateway` configuration.

Comment: You cannot redirect a domain using `A` records alone. The target SSL certificate must support the domain name that you are redirecting, otherwise you will get a security error in the browser/application.

Comment: As correctly stated in previous comment by John Hanley it will be necessary to change the certificates bound to the `ingress-gateway`. This would require additional changes to your `ingress-gateway` definition as the host would be different (assuming it's not `*`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Each method will require some of the reconfiguration in either GKE/Istio side.**

One of the solutions to this is to have a `CNAME` record in a Cloud DNS and a SSL certificate with `Alternative Names`.

With above solution you will be able to send requests to your `GKE/Istio` cluster with both domain names assuming **correct Istio configuration**.

---

What is `CNAME`?

> CNAME is a Canonical Name Record or Alias Record.
>
> A type of resource record in the Domain Name System (DNS), that specifies that one domain name is an alias of another canonical domain name.

Example of a `CNAME` record:

```sh
DNS name       Type      TTL     Data
old.domain.    A         60      1.2.3.4
new.domain.    CNAME     60      old.domain.
```

---

Alternative Names:

> A SAN or subject alternative name is a structured way to indicate all of the domain names and IP addresses that are secured by the certificate.
>
> *[Enstrustdatacard.com: What is a san and how is it used](https://www.entrustdatacard.com/blog/2019/march/what-is-a-san-and-how-is-it-used)*

You can create SSL cerificate create to support both:

- `old.domain`
- `new.domain`

There are plenty options to do that for example Let's Encrypt or Cert Manager.

---

## Example

I've created an example to show you how to do it:

- Configure `DNS zone` in Cloud DNS
- Create a basic app with a service
- Create a certificate for example app
- Create `Istio` resources to allow connections to example app
- Test

### Configure `DNS zone` in Cloud DNS

You will need to have 2 records:

- **`A` record with IP of your Ingress Gateway and name: `old.domain`**
- `CNAME` record pointing to `old.domain` with name: `new.domain`

Please take a look on official documentation: [Cloud.google.com: DNS: Records](https://cloud.google.com/dns/records)

### Create a basic app with a service

Below is example app with a service which will respond with a basic hello:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-dp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-dp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-dp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0"
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-sv
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-dp
  ports:
    - name: hello-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 50001
      targetPort: 50001
  type: ClusterIP
```

### Create a certificate for example app

As said previously, certificate with `Alternative Names` can be created with Let's Encrypt. I created it with:

- GCE VM with Ubuntu 16.04
- Open port 80
- Domain name `old.domain` pointing to public ip address of a VM
- Guide: [Linode.com: Docs: Install let's encrypt to create a SSL certificate](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates/)
- Command to create certificate:

  > `$ ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d`**`old.domain`**`-d`**`new.domain`**
- Certificate created in /etc/letsencrypt/archive/ used in creating tls secret for `GKE` with command:

  > `$ kubectl create secret tls`**`ssl-certificate`**`--cert cert1.pem --key privkey1.pem`

**Please have in mind that this certificate was created only for testing purposes and I strongly advise using dedicated solution like: [Cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager)**

PS: **If you used this method please revert back changes in the Cloud DNS to point the `Istio` gateway.**

---

#### Create `Istio` resources to allow connections to example app

Below are example `Istio` resources allowing connections to example app with support for HTTPS:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hello-gw
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: ssl-certificate
    hosts:
    - "old.domain"
    - "new.domain"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hello-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "old.domain"
  - "new.domain"
  gateways:
  - hello-gw
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: hello-sv
        port:
          number: 50001
```

Please take a specific look on:

```yaml
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: ssl-certificate
```

This part will ensure that connection to the cluster will use HTTPS

Additionally:

```yaml
  hosts:
  - "old.domain"
  - "new.domain"
```

Above definition in both resources will allow only connections with specified domains.

### Test

When applied all of the above resources you should be able to enter in your browser:

- `https://old.domain`
- `https://new.domain`

and be greeted with below message and valid SSL certificate:

```sh
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello-dp-5dd8b85b56-bk7zr
```